# Spark job failing in YARN mode

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark program written in Scala that read a CSV file from HDFS, compute a new column and save it as a parquet file. I am running the program in a YARN cluster. But every time I try to launch it the executors fails at some point with this error.

Could you help me to find what might cause this error ?

Log from on executor

```
16/10/27 15:58:10 WARN storage.BlockManager: Putting block rdd_12_225 failed due to an exception
16/10/27 15:58:10 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block rdd_12_225 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory
16/10/27 15:58:10 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 225.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 465)
java.io.IOException: Stream is corrupted
    at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4BlockInputStream.refill(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:211)
    at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4BlockInputStream.read(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:125)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeRowSerializerInstance$$anon$3$$anon$1.readSize(UnsafeRowSerializer.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeRowSerializerInstance$$anon$3$$anon$1.<init>(UnsafeRowSerializer.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeRowSerializerInstance$$anon$3.asKeyValueIterator(UnsafeRowSerializer.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader$$anonfun$3.apply(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader$$anonfun$3.apply(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$3$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$3$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:866)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4Exception: Error decoding offset 15385 of input buffer
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4JNIFastDecompressor.decompress(LZ4JNIFastDecompressor.java:39)
    at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4BlockInputStream.refill(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:205)
    ... 41 more
```

EDIT :

There is the code used

```
var df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").csv(hdfsFileURLIn).repartition(nPartitions)
df.printSchema()
df = df.withColumn("ipix", a2p(df.col(deName), df.col(raName))).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
df.repartition(nPartitions, $"ipix").write.mode("overwrite").option("spark.hadoop.dfs.replication", 1).parquet(hdfsFileURLOut)
```

the user function a2p is just taking two Double and return an other double

I need to say that this worked well with relatively small CSV (~1Go) but this error happen every times with bigger ones (~15Go)

EDIT 2:
Following the suggestions I disabled the repartition and I used StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY

With this I don't get the Putting block rdd_***** failed due to an exception but there is still an exception related to LZ4 (Stream is corrupted):

```
16/10/28 07:53:00 ERROR util.Utils: Aborting task
java.io.IOException: Stream is corrupted
    at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4BlockInputStream.refill(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:211)
    at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4BlockInputStream.available(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:109)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:353)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.ByteStreams.read(ByteStreams.java:899)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.ByteStreams.readFully(ByteStreams.java:733)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeRowSerializerInstance$$anon$3$$anon$1.next(UnsafeRowSerializer.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeRowSerializerInstance$$anon$3$$anon$1.next(UnsafeRowSerializer.scala:110)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.next(Iterator.scala:444)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.next(CompletionIterator.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4Exception: Error decoding offset 12966 of input buffer
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4JNIFastDecompressor.decompress(LZ4JNIFastDecompressor.java:39)
    at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4BlockInputStream.refill(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:205)
    ... 25 more
```

EDIT 3 : I managed to launch it without any errors by removing also the second repartition (the one that repartition using the column ipix) I will look further in the documentation of this method

EDIT 4 : This is strange, occasionally some executors fail with a segmentation fault :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f48d8a47f2c, pid=3501, tid=0x00007f48cc60c700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 4713 C2 org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.hashCode()I (18 bytes) @ 0x00007f48d8a47f2c [0x00007f48d8a47e60+0xcc]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1477580152295_0008/container_1477580152295_0008_01_000006/core or core.3501
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1477580152295_0008/container_1477580152295_0008_01_000006/hs_err_pid3501.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I checked the memory and all my executors always have plenty of free memory (at least 6Go)

EDIT 4 : So I tested with multiple files and the execution always succeed but sometime some executors fails (with the error above) and are started again by YARN

Comment: Add your code to explore more..

Comment: @Shankar done .

Comment: did you try without repartition? just a guess..

Comment: could you try without persisting to memory, only disk ?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of lz4-java are you using? This may be related to the problem that was fixed in version 1.1.2 -- see this [bug report](https://github.com/jpountz/lz4-java/issues/13)

Also, I am curious about your function a2p. It should ideally take two Column objects as input, and not just Doubles (unless you registered it as a UDF).

Comment: Yes I registered it with udf. EDIT : how can I know the version of LZ4 ?

Comment: You should be able to find it, for example, in the jar MANIFEST file or in your project's dependencies

Comment: I have also 1.3.0 but still I am facing this problem.

Comment: Looking through the stack trace for a Spark 2.0.0 app experiencing this same error (which has dependency on net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:1.3.0), I do not see any references to either net.jpountz.lz4 or lz4-java. Instead there are references to org.apache.spark.io.LZ4BlockInputStream, so maybe Spark 2 is instead using a broken internal reference implementation of lz4?

```java.io.IOException: Stream is corrupted
        at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4BlockInputStream.refill(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:163)
        at org.apache.spark.io.LZ4BlockInputStream.read(LZ4BlockInputStream.java:125)```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue.

Symptoms look exactly like this [problem: SPARK-18105](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18105?focusedCommentId=15844789&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15844789).

As of 1/29/17 it is not fixed yet.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced lz4-java jar to it's latest version (lz4-java-1.5.0.jar) in jars directory of inside SPARK_HOME path. This worked for me.