# Where does sqlContext.read...load() and sqlContext.write...save() code runs on Spark Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I am using Spark Dataframe API for loading/reading file from NFS Share and then saving/writing the data of that file to HDFS.

I have a three node Spark Cluster with One Master node and two Worker nodes. My Spark Cluster is using YARN as Cluster Manager, hence the two Worker nodes are the YARN NodeManager Nodes and master node is Yarn ResourceManager node.

I have a remote location say /data/files which is mounted to all the three YARN/SPARK nodes as it is [/data/files] where all the csv files [more than one] are present which I want to read from and finally write to HDFS.

I am running following code on my master node

```
import java.io.File
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object TestMoreThan1CSV2DF {
  private val source: String = "file:///data/files/"
  private val destination = "hdfs://<myHostIP>:8020/raw/"
  private val fileFormat : String = "com.databricks.spark.csv"

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestMoreThan1CSV2DF").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val fileArray: Array[File] = new java.io.File(source).listFiles.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".csv"))

    for(file<-fileArray){
//  reading csv file from shared location and taking whole data in a dataframe
    var df = loadCSV2DF(sqlContext, fileFormat, "true", "true", file.getName)

//      variable for holding destination location : HDFS Location
    var finalDestination: String = destination+file.getName

//  saving data into HDFS
    writeDF2HDFS(df,fileFormat,"true",finalDestination) /// saved using default number of partition = 1
    }
  }

 def loadCSV2DF(sqlContext : SQLContext, fileFormat: String, header : String, inferSchema: String, source: String) : DataFrame = {
   try{
       sqlContext.read.format(fileFormat)
                       .option("header", header) // Use first line of all files as header
                       .option("inferSchema", inferSchema) // Automatically infer data types
                       .load(source)
   }
   catch{
     case ex: OnboardingException => {
            throw ex;
        }
   }
 }

 def writeDF2HDFS(df: DataFrame, fileFormat: String, header: String, destination: String, partitions: Integer = 1){
   try{
       df.repartition(partitions).write.format(fileFormat).option("header",header).save(destination)
   }
   catch{
     Case ez : OnboardingException => {
            throw ez;
        }
   }
 }
}
```

> This code reads all the csv files present at shared location
>   /data/files/ and write each one of them to HDFS. Ex:
>   /data/files/f1.csv will get loaded into HDFS as /raw/f1.csv/part-xxxxx
>   file

While running this code, I am not able to make out:

> 1) Where this whole code is running? Is it running on driver? or using
>   both workers?
>
> 2) Does load() and save() API runs on worker nodes, does
>   it work in parallel? If yes then how does two workers keeps track of
>   the portion of while which it has read or written?
>
> 3) As of now I am
>   reading each file sequentially in "for" loop and working on each one
>   of them sequentially, is it possible to make it a multi threaded
>   application, where each file is allocated to one thread for performing
>   end to end read and write in parallel. Will disk IO be any constraint
>   while doing this?

Any quick response/reference/pointers would be appreciated.

Regards,
Bhupesh

Answer (score 1):

Very good explanation copied from another thread for my query:
[differentiate driver code and work code in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339200/differentiate-driver-code-and-work-code-in-apache-spark)

Copying some part of it here as well:
Everything that happens inside the closure created by a transformation happens on a worker. It means if something is passed inside map(...), filter(...), mapPartitions(...), groupBy*(...), aggregateBy*(...) is executed on the workers. It includes reading data from a persistent storage or remote sources.

Actions like count, reduce(...), fold(...) are usually executed on both driver and workers. Heavy lifting is performed in parallel by the workers and some final steps, like reducing outputs received from the workers, is performed sequentially on the driver.

Everything else, like triggering an action or transformation happens on the driver. In particular it means every action which requires access to SparkContext.

As far as my queries are concern:
1) Yes part of main() method runs on driver but transformations happens on

2) load() and save() runs on workers as we could see that loading creates dataframe [which gets stored in memory in partitions] and save creates part-xxxx files in hdfs which shows that workers are doing that

3) Still trying to achieve this, will answer this once done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good Experiment!!.

1) your code always runs on worker. driver program just to manage workers.

2) yes load() and save() API runs on worker nodes. and they work sequentially.

3) using multi threaded application : i have not tried yet. good luck to you "go for a try !!". but why do you want put your self in a complex situation !!. SPARK knows how to handle this situations.

Comment: Hi @Achyuta nanda sahoo, thanks for responding. My assumption was all transformation code runs on workers whereas rest of the code runs on driver. Finally action runs either on worker or driver. I am still not clear if my understanding is correct. If load() and save() works on worker nodes then how does it keeps track of which portion of file is read/written by which worker??? If you have liked the question then please give it a up point so that most people could reach to it and provided their valuable comments as like you did.

Comment: main action always takes place from driver node. main action means to get aggregated data from all node. main driver acts like root node . in a tree structure graph , root node is driver and rest are worker node. main driver tries to create partition / index . partition means group data cluster from a file or multiple file. and send each cluster to each node. that's it.